# Are quantum dot’s immobile?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, kinematics, nanoscience

In a recently closed question regarding the cooling of quantum dots through lasers has one of the commentators state that this is in fact impossible as QD’s are immobile:
[Can quantum dots temperature be lowered with Doppler cooling?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665128/can-quantum-dots-temperature-be-lowered-with-doppler-cooling)

In what sense are QD’s immobile in reference to this question?